# MySQL search in PHP based on keyphrases

Tags: php, mysql, search, search-engine

I am writing a prototype auction/listings project in PHP (MySQL backend).

I have a listing table (listings), and a keyphrase table (listings_keyphrases) which has multiple keyphrases describing each item.  Each listing has multiple keyphrases (as many as necessary), but each keyphrase is character-limited to 20 characters.

So in listings_keyphrases there could be, say, 6 rows for a single listing, each with a different keyphrase.  Keyphrases in the listings_keyphrases table are ordered.

I want to implement a search function that:

1. Searches all the keyphrases related to a particular item
2. Sorts results based on:

   - phrasing (if a search phrase matches exactly with a specific keyphrase)
   - keyphrase order (I presume that if a search matches a keyphrase at position 1 that is is more relevant).

I've looked into MySQL FULLTEXT and a few other options but haven't worked out what's the best way forward.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try one of the following search engines:

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

http://sphinxsearch.com/

Both of them are open source, well documented and easy to use.

Comment: This is a good suggestion - use better suited software for the job. I would also like to throw the very nice [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) in the mix.

Comment: [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) looks good at a quick glance, and also [xapian](http://xapian.org/).
But I don't want to suggest something I never actually used.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must use fulltext to search because of one of the sort results you give: if a search phrase matches exactly with a specific keyphrase. With fulltext search it will be the result with more score.

For the second order you give, you have to define some kind of relevance (instead of the relevance of fulltext). When you search some keyphrase mysql does not care if it is the first or last, you have to tell it. if the order of insert keyphases is important you can order results by the relevance of fulltext search AND for ID_keyphrase  (assuming ID_keyphrase is autonumeric) or you can add a field to indicate your relevance or you can use the position (but position as a field in database).

An example:

```
Keyphrase_table
-----------
ID
listing_table_id
keyphrase
relevance
```

with this you can have:

```
1   1  keyphrase2  1
2   1  keyphrase1  2
3   2  keyphrase1  1
```

the listing with id=1 have 2 keyphrase (keyphrase2 and keyphrase1) and the listing with id=2 have 1 keyphrase (keyphrase1)

if you search for "keyphrase1" with fulltext the results will be the record 2 and 3. all 2 results have the same relevance to fulltext because both are the same, but if you add as an order the new field "relevance" in your search (`Order by THE_RELEVANCE_OF_FULLTEXT DESC,relevance ASC`) the record 3 will be the first always because it meets the requeriments of fulltext and is in results lowest position.